# What does the word "democrat" mean in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

What does the word *democrat* mean in the following sentence?

> Effective sales management is a great democrat for smaller firms.

Comment: Can we get more context? This sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: [here it is](http://books.google.com/books?id=4EvbC_KNjSAC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22effective+sales+management+is+a+great+democrat+for+smaller+firms+%22&source=bl&ots=4P8hyPBHtv&sig=y-cPMXQKd2gk0YtLOgVkJO5ZUic&hl=en&ei=fDavTL_aMYySswb-xPDXDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22effective%20sales%20management%20is%20a%20great%20democrat%20for%20smaller%20firms%20%22&f=false).

Comment: @RegDwight: Ok. Well, it still doesn't make sense to me.  I can puzzle out a meaning but it feels like the author is using the word incorrectly.

Comment: I'm merely providing the context, not saying that it adds any sense. (^_^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A great democrat* would mean a great means to give you equal opportunities. In democracy everybody has the same chance, rights, weight, or vote.

Therefore, a great democrat would make sure that all have a leveled playing field.

Comment: Or it might mean the guy from marketing is smoking the good stuff now.

Comment: It means absolutely nothing to me, and I would suppose that it is a mistake, though I can't see what for.

Comment: @Colin: funnily enough, the quote seems to be taken [from a book](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22effective+sales+management+is+a+great+democrat+for+smaller+firms+%22) (rather than, say, from a quick-and-dirty blog comment).

Comment: So, perhaps "equalizer" would be a one-word equivalent? "effective sales management is a great equalizer for smaller firms [attempting to compete with larger firms]."

Comment: Agreed on "equalizer" -- searching the book for other instances of "democrat," you find `Technology is the great democrat.`  Makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can sort of see it, but to me it was opaque and still doesn't fit, because a "democrat" is a person who believes or practices something, whereas this refers to a tool by which the democrat may effect his aims. Unless this is an established usage in some field, I think the writer has committed the sin of mistifying the readers. But hey, what do I know?

Comment: @Colin Fine: I've come across the phrase "...is a great democratizer", with the meaning of "leveller" or "equalizer". Google reveals that using "democratizer" in this way is common, whereas "...is a great democrat" seems to be used more when describing members of the US political party...

Comment: "A great democrat" is not only nonsensical, but an oxymoron as well. :)

Comment: Apologies to all democrats (great and otherwise) for my last comment, but if someone is going to lob them up like that I cannot resist.

Answer (score 7):

The phrase should be "Effective sales management is a great "democratIZER" for small firms. To "democratize" is to make things more "democratic."

Larger firms are more "aristocratic" insofar as they have economies of scale, better connections, deeper pockets, etc. But sales is the lifeblood of business. It is one area where a small firm has a chance to compete successfully with a large firm. That makes things more "democratic."

Comment: Ack... why did you necro this question? I am not sure your answer is correct, either.

Comment: @MrHen: "necro"? Does that mean 'kill'?

Comment: @Mitch: "Necro" in an online context is short for "raising a topic from the dead." It means the same thing as _bump_.

Comment: @Mr. Hen: Because I came across this question for the first time, and wasn't satisfied with the other answer. While the gist wasn't bad, sales management is not a "democrat," it's a "democratizer."

Comment: +1. As written, the sentence makes no sense. I'm about 80% certain that "democratizer" was what was intended. Possibly the author got bit by computer auto-correcting software. I notice mine doesn't know the word.

Comment: @TED: that's 'bitten' in English.  (I'm not sure about American.)

Comment: @TimLymington OED says *bit* can be the past participle: “bite /baɪt/, v. Pa. t. bit /bɪt/. Pa. pple. bitten /ˈbɪt(ə)n/; also bit. *arch.”* It includes a 20th-century UK example of such here: “1955 Times 11 May 14/6 ― ‘Better men than Mr. Strachey have bit the dust in Dundee,’ was how the Tory hopes were summed up by one Conservative.” Also several 18th-century ones, including: “1852 Thackeray Esmond iii. iii. 340 ― Miss Beatrix was quite bit (as the phrase of that day was).”